# convert UIAccelerometer data into Degree in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uiaccelerometer, degrees

any idea how to turn the accelerometer data into degrees? i have developed an accelerometer application and i need to get the values in degree?

```
  UIAccelerometer *accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
     accel.delegate = self;
     accel.updateInterval = 1.0f/50.0f;

- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)acel didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)aceler 
    {

          NSLog(@"%f %f %f",aceler.x,aceler.y,aceler.z);

    }
```

i need the values in degree ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple example for the X-Y angle:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)acel didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)aceler 
{
   // get angle in radians
   float angle = atan2(aceler.x, aceler.y);
   // convert to degrees
   float angleInDegrees = (angle * 180/M_PI);
   NSLog(@"%f degrees",angleInDegrees); 
}
```

Comment: but in some applications i seen like, the degree shows 45, 35, -30 etc... ,, angleInDegrees prints some floating value

Comment: Apologies: I have edited the code to correct a stupid typo. This will now give you +/- 180.